# How can I transfer a date to another input field?

Tags: jquery, input, bootstrap-datepicker

I want to display my selected date from `.startdate_input` in my input field `startdate`. And when I empty the `.startdate_input` field, the `.startdate` field should also be empty again.

http://jsfiddle.net/93eTU/2524/

```
<input type="text" class="startdate_input date form-control" value="">
 <input value="" name="startdate" class="startdate" type="text">



<script>
 $('.date').datepicker({
     dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
     minDate: '+5d',
     changeMonth: true,
     changeYear: true,
     altField: "#idTourDateDetailsHidden",
     altFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
 });

     function dateformat(date, output) {
        var date_f = $(date).val();
        if (date_f == '') {
            var result = '';
        } else {
            var result = moment(date_f, "DD/MM/YYYY").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:00");
            $(output).val(result);
        }
    }

  $("input, select").on("change keyup paste", function () {
 dateformat(".startdate_input", ".startdate");
  });

</script>
```

I do not get any results in my input field `.startdate`

Comment: JSfiddle not working, check console error

Comment: Do you need http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/bh8godjn/? You were close then.

Comment: @Satpal What did you change to make it work?

Comment: Added `$(output).val('');` and moment library. I would recommend you to bind `change` event handler as `$('.date').datepicker({
 }).on("input change", function(e) {
   dateformat(".startdate_input", ".startdate");
 });`

Comment: Ok! Great, thank you. I missed that

Comment: Ah, ok, thank you for the advice

Answer (score 1):

You were already really close, however there were a few issues with your code:
Firstly `$("input, select").on("change keyup paste", function () {
 dateformat(".startdate_input", ".startdate");
  });` should be done after the full document is loaded, so that it doesn't run before the actual inputs are loaded.
Secondly, there were some scope issues in your dateformat function (when outputting the result if it's empty, it won't know the value of the result variable because it isn't declared in this case.
Lastly, but maybe this was only a problem in your fiddle, moment.js wasn't included (I've added it in the fiddle provided below).

I've fixed those issues here:

```
 $('.date').datepicker({
     dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
     minDate: '+5d',
     changeMonth: true,
     changeYear: true,
     altField: "#idTourDateDetailsHidden",
     altFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
 });

 function dateformat(date, output) {
    var date_f = $(date).val();
    var result = '';
    if (date_f != '') {
        var result = moment(date_f, "DD/MM/YYYY").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:00");
    }
    $(output).val(result);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input, select").on("change keyup paste", function () {
            dateformat(".startdate_input", ".startdate");
    })
  });
```

You can also see it running here: http://jsfiddle.net/rqb21bo0/